# Obtener archivo desde assets en Angular

Tags: angular

Hola amigos tengo una imagen en assets en la cual quiero obtenerlo que sea de tipo de File para enviarlo en un post, si alguien me podria ayudar gracias

```js
const foto = 'assets/img/No_image_available.svg'
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer?

Comment: solo quiero obtener esa imagen en formato File solo eso pero no se como

Comment: pero has intentado algo para obtener eso?